# Setting Alpha Channel on new Unity UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am working on a thirst system. I want to set the Alpha of the Image to the thirst number mod 255 to set it to a number near 255 so it is in the 255 range for the alpha. Why can't I just set the Alpha to that number. I've tested and if I do -= and I chose a number it will go down. Any solutions?

Here is my code

```
void Update() {
    currentThirst -= Time.deltaTime / 2;
    currentHunger -= Time.deltaTime / 2;

    Color temp = thirstImage.color;
    temp.a = (currentThirst % 255);
    thirstImage.color = temp;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use unity tag when the question is not about Microsoft Unity.

Comment: Oh sorry. I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color, in Unity3D, expects a float value from 0 to 1, so I would recommend doing something like:

```
temp.a = (currentThirst % 255) / 255.0f;
```

to convert from your 0 to 255 expectations into a 0 to 1 float value.
Hope this helps.